# separate certain characters when matched from either direction regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have something like this:

```
text = "hey;)there"
```

Need this:

```
text = "hey ;) there"
```

I am doing 2 passes:

```
op_1 = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])([:;()])', r'\1 \2', text)
final_result = re.sub(r'([:;()])([a-zA-Z])', r'\1 \2', op_1)
```

I am sure there must be an efficient way for this.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about the cases you do and don't want to handle? What's the actual task here?

Comment: just want to separate a few characters that don't match '\w', say for emoticons

Comment: In that case, would `r'(\W{2,})'` do it? Then you can just replace it with `r' \1 '` - https://regex101.com/r/kM4qZ9/1

Comment: @jonrsharpe gives me this ''hi \x01 there'' :)

Comment: You left out the `r`, which means *"raw string"*, you'd have to use `' \\1 '` to escape the backslash.

Comment: it gives `hi ;)there :)` for the text `hi;)there:)` but I need `hi ;) there :)` (the second space is missing). Is that possible ? :)

Comment: That's not what I see: https://regex101.com/r/kM4qZ9/2, https://repl.it/C5gw

Comment: Note the regex should be `{2}` for *"precisely two"* or `{2,}` for *"at least two"*. `:`, `-` and `)` are all matched by `\W`.

Comment: You're right...Sorry for not noticing it. But I feel I've a bit of flexibility on what chars to filter for (even in `\W` space (e.g., `@`)) with the accepted solution below. Otherwise, your solution is concise and fits perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaheads and lookbehinds with alternation

```
>>> re.sub('(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[:;()])|(?<=[:;()])(?=[a-zA-Z])', ' ', text)
'hey ;) there'
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z]) #Lookbehind to match an alphabet
(?=[:;()]) #Lookahead to match the position of signs
| Alternation(OR)
(?<=[:;()]) #Lookbehind to match the position of signs
(?=[a-zA-Z]) #Lookahead to match an alphabet
```

Comment: the result is not the same. :) a couple of characters are  missing. I just want to separate the pattern.

Comment: Note that you can include explanations inline if you use triple-quoted `r"""raw strings"""` and the `re.VERBOSE` flag, often handy for keeping the information with the code.

Comment: @Kevad what characters are missing?

Comment: I need 'hey ;) there', the above snippet gives 'he ;) here'

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: @Kevad i am assuming(and it seems) you are trying to match emoji..so i am not including non word condition

Comment: @rock321987 in this example yes... but your solution can be used to include/exclude any characters... that's useful when I want to include chars that are in '\w' space. So I feel this is more general.

Comment: @Kevad as you wish..you can use `\W{2}` for non-word character..feel free to give an upvote..:)